# Query for list of installed ACT shims

Tags: windows-7, inventory, shim, act

Does anyone know how I can programmatically obtain a list of installed ACT shims on a given computer?  Are names stored in the Registry somewhere?  I don't need help with scripting, just a little help pointing me to where to look.  Particularly for Windows 7.  TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It's stored in the Registry under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall.  Each entry only has two values: "DisplayName" (which simply shows the filename of the .SDB file), and "UninstallString", which provides the "sdbinst.exe /u [path]\filename.sdb" or the GUID syntax:  %windir%\system32\sdbinst.exe -u "C:\Windows\AppPatch\Custom{...GUID...}.sdb"

Answer (score -1):

This may not find all shims.  Unfortunately, if the shim was installed via MSI custom action, the uninstall record may have been removed.  See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd837647(v=ws.10).aspx

PS: I don't have a better answer to your query than you either.  It might have to involve dissecting the sdb the crap is installed into.

Tim